# Checking an output for specific extentions in if statement

Tags: shell-script, tar, dpkg

I am trying to write a script where I have an if statement that has to check if a specific folder contains a package with specific extensions. If so, it then has to unpack it.

```
if [ installation = "1" ]; then
    if ls /usr/local/src grep -qF ".tar.gz"; then
        tar -zxvf $package #it has to unpack the package
    elif ls /usr/local/src grep -qF ".tar.bz2"; then
        tar -xvfj $package #it has to unpack the package
    fi
    ./configure
elif [ installation = "2" ]; then
    dpkg -i $package #it has to install the deb package
fi
```

Can it be written in this way?

The `$package` is not used, but I've written it to show you what I mean. I don't know how to let it know that it has to unpack/install the founded folder with the extension .tar.gz or .tar.bz2 or .deb

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question I feel like I should point out that (assuming GNU tar) [the only time you need to specify the compression type ( like `-j` & `-z` above ) is when tar can not examine the file](http://superuser.com/questions/689818/let-tar-auto-detect-compression-type-when-extracting-from-stdin/689845#689845). like through a pipe/stdin. So you could simplify it down to `tar -xvf $package` with no need for the if block

Comment: @ZacharyBrady so you suggest that I should change it to -xvf for both packages namely tar.gz & tar.bz2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
 #!/bin/bash

cd /usr/local/src
    if [ installation = "1" ]; then
        for package in *.tar.gz
        do
            tar -zxvf "${package}"
        done

        for package in *.tar.bz2
        do
            tar -xvfj "$package" #it has to unpack the package
        done
        ./configure
    elif [ installation = "2" ]; then
        dpkg -i "$package" #it has to install the deb package
    fi
```

Comment: the variabel package, what does it contain? Where does it get its content? I mean how does it know that it's this specific folder. Let's take `if [ installation = "1" ]; then
        for package in *.tar.gz
        do
            tar -zxvf ${package}
        done` Does `package` get its content from here: `for package in *.tar.gz`?

Comment: its from /usr/local/src

cd /usr/local/src

Comment: So it will know that without knowing the name of the package, but only the extension?

Comment: first we go to that directory and search if any .tar.gz file there inside.. if yes.. then it untar the file.

Comment: @terdon; why are you editing? Was it incorrect?

Comment: @Hudhud no, not incorrect, as such. I just made it safe for edge cases such as when your filenames contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this.

```
if [ installation = "1" ]; then
    for package in *.tar.*
    do
        tar -xvf ${package} # Unpack (Let tar detect compression type)
    done
    ./configure
elif [ installation = "2" ]; then
    dpkg -i ${deb_package} #it has to install the deb package
fi
```

There is no need to manually detect the compression type through `ls`/`grep` hacks.

> The only case when you have to specify a decompression option while
>   reading the archive is when reading from a pipe or from a tape drive
>   that does not support random access. However, in this case GNU tar
>   will indicate which option you should use. For example:
>
> ```
> $ cat archive.tar.gz | tar tf -
> tar: Archive is compressed.  Use -z option
> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
> ```
>
> If you see such diagnostics, just add the suggested option to the
>   invocation of GNU tar:
>
> ```
> $ cat archive.tar.gz | tar tzf -
> ```

-- [8.1.1 Creating and Reading Compressed Archives](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html)

Comment: I use that for both `tar.gz` & `tar.bz2`?

Comment: @Hudhud yes `tar` is smart enough to tell the difference between bzip2 compression (.bz2) and gzip compression (.gz). The only time you have to specify a compression type is with GNU `tar` when you're sending it data through a pipe like this `cat archive.tar.gz | tar tzf -` aside from that `tar `will handle it for you.

Comment: But I still need to tell the script which extension it can unpack so I thought about doing this way;    `for package in *.tar.gz && *.tar.bz2
        do
            tar -xvf ${package}
        done`

Comment: Updated my answer with a for loop assuming all the file are in your working directory.

Comment: Is wrtting `${deb_package}` necessarily ? Can't I just write `${package}`

Comment: I changed it to deb_package because you're using package in the for loop, we're not defining deb_package anywhere in the answer. I just did it to prevent confusion. You can call the variable whatever you'd like.

Comment: So the script does the following: if installation equals 1 then it at the package with extension tar and unpacks it and runs configure else if installation equals 2 then it installs the deb package. How does it know that working directory has a .deb package? I know I install it, but in the other look at if the names contains tar